# Convert OLECHAR* to CHAR* in order to build string()

Tags: c++, c, winapi, com

I have a OLECHAR* and i want to convert it CHAR* in order to create string out of it, i didnt find a way of doing it.

Is OLECHAR is a regular char ? didnt the idea of it.

Thanks in advance,
Gal.

Comment: It's a string of wide characters. If by `string`, you mean `std::string`, why not just use `std::wstring`?

Comment: is there a way to convert it to regular string ?

Comment: Of course. There are several, including `std::wstring_convert`.

Comment: working with VC6, dont think its available there ..

Answer (score 4):

`OLECHAR` is a string of `wchar_t` characters. I recommend reading [The Complete Guide to C++ Strings, Part II - String Wrapper Classes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3004/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-II-String-Wra).

Answer (score 2):

`OLECHAR*` is a Unicode (UTF-16) `wchar_t` string. If you want to convert it to a `CHAR*` string, you have to clarify what particular encoding you are going to use for the conversion.

For example, you may want to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 (which is a non-lossy conversion), and you can store an UTF-8 string in `char*`/`std::string` (I prefer using robust string classes instead of raw pointers in C++ code).

To perform the conversion, you can use the [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API. You can use the `CP_UTF8` "code page" value if you want to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8. For a (potentially lossy) "ANSI" conversion, you can use `CP_ACP`, etc.

(There are also [convenient ATL wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the aforementioned Win32 API, like `CW2A`, but I'm not sure what level of functionality is available in VC6's version of these wrappers.)